# Volume of the convex hull of the rows of a circulant matrix

Tags: matrices, volume, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls, circulant-matrices

What is the formula for volume of the convex hull of the rows of a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)?

Comment: The $n$-volume of the convex hull is $0$. This is because the convex hull of the $n$ row vectors lie on a hyperplane $x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1} =  c_0 + c_1 + \cdots + c_{n-1}$. Do you mean the $(n−1)$-volume of the convex hull with respect to the hyperplane it lies on? That will be $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k}$ of the determinant of the circulant matrix.

Comment: @achillehui it is not determinant! is it?